# chaning id of multiple select at runtime using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have problem when i want to set different id for select at runtime, number of select may be four or more but i need all have different id
can anybody help me to find select at runtime and assign different id to each select at runtime using javascript.

```
<div  id="div1"  >
<select >
<option value="OPTION 1" >OPTION 1</option>
</select>

<select>
<option value="OPTION 1" >OPTION 1</option>
</select>

<select>
<option value="OPTION 1" >OPTION 1</option>
</select>

<select>
<option value="OPTION 1" >OPTION 1</option>
</select>

<select >
<option value="OPTION 1" >OPTION 1</option>
</select>
.
.
.
.
<select >
```

Comment: Are the select tags dynamically created?

Answer (score 0):

Just get a reference all of the selects, then iterate over them and set the id accordingly.

```
var i = 0; // or whatever
$("select").each(function(){
  this.id = i;
  i++
});
```

I have used this method as opposed to passing an index to the callback, as you can then change id to a different value more easily.

If you don't need to do this, then @Adil's method is neater.

Answer (score 0):

First of all find all the `selects` withing div having id `div1`. Now you can use [.each( function(index, Element) )](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to assign id to each `select`.

```
$('#div1 select').each(function(index, obj){
    obj.id = "sel" + index;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var selected = $('select option:selected').val();
  $('select').attr('id',selected);
```

Comment: Or you can also assign index of the selected item,

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('select').prop('id', function(index, old) {
  return old || 'select_' + index;
});
```

It sets a new `id` property if the element doesn't have one yet.

If this needs to be applied multiple times, it would be better to use a dedicated id generator:

```
var idGenerator = function(prefix) {
  var num = 0;

  return function() {
    return prefix + num++;
  }
}('select_');

$('select').prop('id', idGenerator);
```